# Postgres update from select

Tags: postgresql

Есть две большие таблицы.

```
tbl_a
id, cnt

tbl_b
id, a_id
```

Нужно в таблицу `tbl_a` в колонку `cnt` загнать количество строк с `a_id=tbl_a.id` в таблице `tbl_b`.

запрос

```
update tbl_a
set cnt = tb.c
from (select count(*),a_id from tbl_b group by a_id) tb
where tb.a_id = tbl_a.id
```

,который советуют на **SO** работает потрясающе долго (примерно **0,8**с на каждую тысячу обновляемых строк, а строк - несколько лямов). Пробовал создавать временную таблицу

```
... AS (select count(*),a_id from tbl_b group by a_id)
```

и даже прикручивал к ней индекс по `a_id`, но все без толку (почему-то эксплейн сообщает, что происходит Seq Search вместо Index Search).

Можно ли это же устроить быстрее?

**N.B.** это Postgres. `Update ... left join` тут не прокатит.

Comment: `update tbl_a set cnt = (select count(*) from tbl_b where tbl_b.a_id=tbl_a.id)` тоже плохо или вообще не работает?

Answer (score 1):

На данный момент проблема решена составлением списка с одинаковыми `tb.c` и обновлением через `where in`. Получилось быстро, но неуниверсально.